# I am using pandas how can I read a file with the delimeter "?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have tried using sep='"' but python wont read it. I am currently using Spyder with python3

```
Período"Código_Grupo_CUODE"Grupo_CUODE"Código_Subpartida"Subpartida"País_Origen"TM_Peso_Neto"FOB"CIF
2000 / 01 - Ene"01"BIENES DE CONSUMO NO DURADERO"0201200000"Los demás cortes (trozos) sin deshuesar"ESTADOS UNIDOS"0,204"0,986"1,237
2000 / 01 - Ene"01"BIENES DE CONSUMO NO DURADERO"0201300000"Deshuesada"ESTADOS UNIDOS"0,248"1,527"1,835
2000 / 08 - Ago"01"BIENES DE CONSUMO NO DURADERO"0201300000"Deshuesada"ESTADOS UNIDOS"1,337"17,754"20,86
2000 / 09 - Sep"01"BIENES DE CONSUMO NO DURADERO"0201300000"Deshuesada"ARGENTINA"1,017"9,526"10,8
2000 / 10 - Oct"01"BIENES DE CONSUMO NO DURADERO"0201300000"Deshuesada"ESTADOS UNIDOS"0,278"6,367"7,052
2000 / 07 - Jul"01"BIENES DE CONSUMO NO DURADERO"0202200000"Los demás cortes (trozos) sin deshuesar"ESTADOS UNIDOS"0,233"3,24"3,552
2000 / 08 - Ago"01"BIENES DE CONSUMO NO DURADERO"0202200000"Los demás cortes (trozos) sin deshuesar"ESTADOS UNIDOS"3,422"11,545"12,464
2000 / 09 - Sep"01"BIENES DE CONSUMO NO DURADERO"0202200000"Los demás cortes (trozos) sin deshuesar"ARGENTINA"0,072"0,361"0,626
2000 / 12 - Dic"01"BIENES DE CONSUMO NO DURADERO"0202200000"Los demás cortes (trozos) sin deshuesar"ESTADOS UNIDOS"3,488"9,056"9,852
```

[CSV Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuPxZ.jpg)

Comment: Post a few lines of this data. You say that the quote character is the separator? Or are they quoted strings?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I created a two line CSV as `foo"bar\n1"2` then did `pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='"')` and it worked. Please add sample file and script to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(r"E:\Bases\Importaciones\M 2000-2016.csv", sep='"')

Comment: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 9 fields in line 1849, saw 233 i get this error

Comment: If you don't post some data, there is nothing we can do. Grab a few lines from this CSV and post them here as a code block. Of, just make something up that shows the problem. I took a few minues making a test file, you can too.

Comment: Posting an image doesn't help. Post the example as text so we can use it.

Comment: And let us know which api you are using. Are you reading a CSV, an XLS? That means including a minimal example script.

Comment: I am currently using spyder an its a csv file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IH9kOO1dMgKNsVIYhBlaMCBeugQrrWDe/view?usp=sharing

Comment: "spyder"? Can you show the import and the function call you use? Using your posted data, it works for me with `pandas.read_csv("M 2000-2006.csv", sep='"')`.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSV file contains a BOM at the start and uses a UTF-8 encoding, the following should be able to read the first 1000 rows of the file:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('M 2000-2016.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig', sep='"', nrows=1000)
```

Unfortunately some later rows also contain faulty doublequoting, for example:

```
2000 / 01 - Ene"01"BIENES DE CONSUMO NO DURADERO"1905300000""Galletas dulces (con adicion de edulcorante); barquillos y obleas, incluso rellenos (""gaufrettes"", ""wafers"") y ""waffles"" (""gaufres"")""ALEMANIA0,003""0,005"0,026""
```

Here there is no delimiter between `ALEMANIA` and `0,003`. You would need to write a custom parser if all rows are required.

Comment: Oh, I see Thank you very much, I will try to fix it from the database